# How to get certain key's value from object's method which returns array - in one line of code?

Tags: php, arrays, object

I've got a object instance and I retreive from him some method:

```
$object->getWebUserInfo($id)
```

It returns some typical array:

> array(29) { ["username"]=> string(7) "quardas" ["password"]=> string(32) "PASS" ["id"]=> string(2) "19" ["internalKey"]=> string(2) "19" ["name"]=> string(0) "" ["fullname"]=> string(0) "" ["role"]=> string(1) "0" ["email"]=> string(17) "quardas@somemail.com" ["phone"]=> string(0) "" ["mobilephone"]=> string(0) "" ["blocked"] ... etc

Is it possible to get certain key's value in one line code? (Wihtout make additional value which keeps this array) - e.g.

```
$object->getWebUserInfo($id)->{'username'}
```

of course that above doesn't work

Comment: You should use [crypt](http://php.net/crypt) for your passwords, not md5, which I assume from `string(32)`

Comment: yes yes - is's only example. I often put there md5 hash

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Dereferencing of arrays from methods and functions](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/functionarraydereferencing) is not supported in your version of PHP.  You could, however, typecast the return value to an object and access the items like object members:

```
function getWebUserInfo($id)
{
   ...
   return (object) $array;
}
```

```
$obj->getWebUserInfo($id)->username;
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to modify "getWebUserInfo" function with passing to it a string parameter which returns the key corresponding to this string.

```
function getWebUserInfo($id,$key="") {
    ...;
    $array = ...;
    if($key != "") {
        return $array[$key];
    } else {
        return $array;
    }

};
```

You can pass an array of string in "$key" to returns multiple keys, but you have to modify a little more your function.

Answer (score 2):

You can write a function or methode for this:

```
function getKey($a, $key)
{
    return $a[$key];
}
echo getKey(getWebUserInfo(), 'test');
```

or getWebUserInfoByKey($id, 'test')

http://codepad.org/4VBYwNWE

Comment: its the same solution like JBRTRND-DEV's :) but his is prettier :P thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can't access returned array values directly, sad but you must create temp array for that. LiMuBei your solutions does not work either.

Answer (score 1):

This can't be done in one step, but something like this might work:

```
function get_array_key($array, $key) {
    return (isset($array[$key])) ? $array[$key] : false;
}

...

get_array_key($object->getWebUserInfo($id), 'username');
```

Answer (score 0):

Haven't tested this, but doesn't

```
$object->getWebUserInfo($id)["username"]
```

work? If the method returns an array this should be possible I think.

Comment: next major php version will support this.

Comment: Depends on the version of PHP.... I believe that type of direct referencing of an element returned as an array by a function/method call is new in PHP5.4

Comment: http://schlueters.de/blog/archives/138-Features-in-PHP-trunk-Array-dereferencing.html

Answer (score 0):

That doesn't look like a PHP array... D:

I'm not sure, but you might want to try this, I know, it's two lines of code

```
$temp = $object->getWebUserInfo($id);
echo $temp["username"];
```

Comment: nope.. "wihtout make additional value which keeps this array" :)